# What tire size will provide a softer ride and less oversteer?

Tags: tires, suspension, jeep

I am currently tasked with replacing the tires on my grandparents 07 Jeep Wrangler X with a 225/75/16. To preface this, it will never go offroad! My mom drives my grandma around on Sundays to the mall and errands. I have no plan on replacing the stock 16" rim (Sorry, I can't tell you what the width of the rim is)

Before I go and buy new tires, I want to buy a tire that will best make for a softer ride. I believe a tire with more sidewall helps absorb more bumps. If this is correct, what are the pitfalls of a taller tire?

Also since it has such a short wheel base it turns very well, unfortunately that equates to a lot steering while trying to drive straight on the highway. I believe this is called "oversteer". Would a wider or narrower tire help dampen the steer? If this is correct, what are the pitfalls of a wider/narrower tire?

Thanks Again,
Devin

**[Edit]** 
I think I made my question to practical, if we look at it from a strictly theoretical view. My original question.

What are the pitfalls of a taller tire?
& 
What are the pitfalls of a wider/narrower tire?

For example, a taller tire decreases handling, or a taller tire increases the odds of thicker side walls and increased load ratings (IE truck tires).

I'm just looking for more simple facts about the variables at play when deciding on tire sizing. These facts will help me make an informed decision on which size I should pick based on my criteria.

Thanks Again,
Devin

Comment: Oversteer is when your rear tires loose traction, causing the back end to spin around.  In normal driving, this is most common when it is raining (or snowing), you have a RWD and you are making a turn when pulling away from a light since you are accelerating, and turning on a slippery surface.  For a 225, I would expect the rim to be 6.5" or 7" wide.

Answer (score 5):

Devin-
Jeeps are off-road vehicles are NOT meant to have a soft ride. With that being said, no matter what tire you throw on it the ride quality will not change in this way.

When I bought my Wrangler, I had the same tires you are referring to- Goodyear Wranglers. After about a year I swapped my tires to 265/75 r16 BFG All Terrain TA KO2 (original rim). I noticed immediately the ride quality on the highway and general around town driving improved since the sidewall is significantly stiffer. I think the junk tires they throw on stock Wranglers are not supportive enough and thus make the vehicle feel very unstable if turning quick or making small movements on the highway. Switching to this kind of tire will however make the ride much bumpier!

Unfortunately I don't believe you can make the ride more comfortable for your grandparents but switching to higher quality tires will definitely improve the issues you're experiencing on the highway. Don't forget- if you switch tire sizes (and have an automatic transmission) you MUST recalibrate the speedometer.

Answer (score 3):

I would not think more sidewall would help.  The 75 denotes that you have a large amount of sidewall as it is.  I would think the best place to look for a softer ride is the springs and shocks.

The tire you pick will not effect how straight the vehicle drives.  If it is pulling, you need an alignment.

Personally, I would look on a website like tirerack.com at stock size tires and pay close attention to the reviews.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately the tyres wont make much of a difference for your ride quality, other than noise, road tyres will be much better in that department regardless of the width.

the only thing you can do for the tyres is the pressure, what PSI are you running at, depending on the spec of the tyre itself, if you run a little on the lower side small bumps will be mitigated, but fuel economy and wear will suffer.

for example mine is spec for 50PSI cold and i run close to that because i dont really care about ride quality, but if i was running at ~30 PSI it would be a much smoother ride

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a limited range of tire size options (perhaps only one size) you can fit on the existing rims - you'd have to check with a tire dealer. There are cases where different makes/models of tires of exactly the same size will deliver different ride and handling qualities. Again, you'd have to check with a dealer. Just bear in mind that a more comfy ride usually means a bit of a sacrifice in handling qualities.